# StreamSocketListener and localhost

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using the following code to set up a StreamSocketListener on my universal 8.1 app:

```cs
_listener = new StreamSocketListener();
_listener.Control.QualityOfService = SocketQualityOfService.Normal;
_listener.ConnectionReceived += OnConnectionReceived;
await _listener.BindServiceNameAsync("8776");
```

This runs without any problems, however when I try & browse to `http://localhost:8776` (or directly via ip address or machine name), the request times out.

In netstat I can see the 8776 port is open & listening, I've enabled loopback exemption, disabled my firewall, but I'm still not able to connect. This is true for both the Windows 8.1 and the Windows Phone 8.1 app.

When I try to connect from another machine, it works without problems. Is there any setting/configuration I can use so I'm able to connect from the same machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows RT blocks loopback access between two WinRT applications.

> Network communications using an IP loopback address cannot be used for
>   interprocess communication (between two different apps) in a Windows
>   Runtime app since this is restricted by network isolation. Network
>   communication using an IP loopback address is allowed within an app
>   within the same process for communication purposes.

More info and workaround [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780593.aspx)

Comment: I've added all possible apps to the exemption list via fiddler2, but I get the same behavior.

Comment: From the same article: Note  Loopback is permitted only for development purposes. Usage by a Windows Runtime app installed outside of Visual Studio is not permitted. Further, a Windows Runtime app can use an IP loopback only as the target address for a client network request. So a Windows Runtime app that uses a DatagramSocket or StreamSocketListener to listen on an IP loopback address is prevented from receiving any incoming packets.

Comment: Oh, missed that part. Thanks