# UWP unable to create localhost connection between two apps

Tags: c#, tcp, uwp

I am trying to setup a TCP connection between two UWP apps. It works fine when both server and client are running in the same app. But when I move the server part to one app and the client part to another, the ConnectAsync throws an exception (server does not respond in time).

Both apps have the private networks capability setup. And as I understand from the MSDN pages I don't have to bother with adding an exception in CheckNetIsolation as long as I run the apps in the debugger. (I checked the checkbox in de debug property pages of the project, both have the "Allow local network loopback" enabled.

Firewall is turned off completely too.

I can see in `netstat` that the port is opened and that it's in the listening state:

```
 TCP    0.0.0.0:1337           PC-BAS:0               LISTENING
```

The code I am using is copied from the [MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets) and is unchanged, except for the part the client and server are hosted in two separate apps.

Client:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //this.StartServer();
        this.StartClient();
    }

    private async void StartClient()
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the StreamSocket and establish a connection to the echo server.
            using (var streamSocket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket())
            {
                // The server hostname that we will be establishing a connection to. In this example, the server and client are in the same process.
                var hostName = new Windows.Networking.HostName("127.0.0.1");

                this.clientListBox.Items.Add("client is trying to connect...");

                await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(hostName, StreamSocketAndListenerPage.PortNumber);

                this.clientListBox.Items.Add("client connected");

                // Send a request to the echo server.
                string request = "Hello, World!";
                using (Stream outputStream = streamSocket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite())
                {
                    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream))
                    {
                        await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(request);
                        await streamWriter.FlushAsync();
                    }
                }

                this.clientListBox.Items.Add(string.Format("client sent the request: \"{0}\"", request));

                // Read data from the echo server.
                string response;
                using (Stream inputStream = streamSocket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead())
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
                    {
                        response = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
                    }
                }

                this.clientListBox.Items.Add(string.Format("client received the response: \"{0}\" ", response));
            }

            this.clientListBox.Items.Add("client closed its socket");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketErrorStatus webErrorStatus = Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketError.GetStatus(ex.GetBaseException().HResult);
            this.clientListBox.Items.Add(webErrorStatus.ToString() != "Unknown" ? webErrorStatus.ToString() : ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Server:

```
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        try
        {
            var streamSocketListener = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener();

            // The ConnectionReceived event is raised when connections are received.
            streamSocketListener.ConnectionReceived += this.StreamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived;

            // Start listening for incoming TCP connections on the specified port. You can specify any port that's not currently in use.
            await streamSocketListener.BindServiceNameAsync("1337");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketErrorStatus webErrorStatus = Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketError.GetStatus(ex.GetBaseException().HResult);
        }
    }

    private async void StreamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived(Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener sender, Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        string request;
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead()))
        {
            request = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
        }

        // Echo the request back as the response.
        using (Stream outputStream = args.Socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite())
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream))
            {
                await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(request);
                await streamWriter.FlushAsync();
            }
        }

        sender.Dispose();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

#### Update

I tried to excempt both apps with `checknetisolation`:

> C:\Users\baspr>checknetisolation LoopbackExempt -s
>
> List Loopback Exempted AppContainers
>
> [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets) -----------------------------------------------------------------
>       Name: bb9c7c66-7c8e-4736-b328-1b107e10a7a9_wkb2562a8jp2j
>       SID:  S-1-15-2-762432806-102046223-720402593-3591906639-2980959523-756744333-221970472
>
> [2] -----------------------------------------------------------------
>       Name: client_wkb2562a8jp2j
>       SID:  S-1-15-2-2445159625-2135182799-200836335-1591194441-3000767028-3156876117-3345333685

client:

```
C:\Users\baspr>checknetisolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=client_wkb2562a8jp2j
OK.
```

server:

```
C:\Users\baspr>checknetisolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=bb9c7c66-7c8e-4736-b328-1b107e10a7a9_wkb2562a8jp2j
OK.
```

Although I wonder if that's even necessary as this is stated on MSDN :

> Loopback and the debugger
>
> By default, running under the Visual Studio debugger enables outbound
>   loopback automatically for that debug session only.  You shouldn’t
>   have to do anything as long as the loopback checkbox is checked in the
>   debugger settings for your startup project.  If you want to implement
>   a socket listener the you must enable localhost loopback for inbound
>   connections (see below).

In any event, it doesn't change anything. I still can't connect to the server. I tried both my local IP address as the loopback address (192.168.1.2 and 127.0.0.1). It doesn't work.

Hope anybody can shed a light on this ...

Comment: Ip address 127.0.0.1 is the Loopback address and is only connected to apps on same PC and cannot be used for connecting between two different machines.  A Server should always connect to IPAny so if a machine has more than one IP address it will accept a connection from any ethernet card on the machine.   The client should always connect either to the remote IP address or Machine Name.  It is better to use the machine name because it never changes.  IP address often change especially if you are using DHCP where IP address are change periodically.

Comment: IP loopback address cannot be used for IPC "interprocess communication" see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329043/streamsocketlistener-and-localhost) will help you, so you need to use your IP instead of localhost one.

Comment: @muaz sorry for the late reply, but I don't think your are right. In the MSDN page which is linked in the SO link you provided is clearly stated that for testing purposes loopback is possible. PS: using the IP address iso loopback gives the same results

Comment: Okay, in Visual Studio environment loopback should be enabled automatically. However; in case you are still stumbling with this try: remove all exemptions with this command `LoopbackExempt –c` and remake the exemptions as you did earlier, some people claimed that worked for them.